# Scrollviewer is not scrolling even set scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(100);?

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

ScrollViewer is having hundreds of records and it has image views, these image views are not loading while setting the Scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(100) , am trying to print the VerticalOffset value it shows '0'. This is the major problem i have read some where.But what is the solution for my problem?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I arrived at this solution:

```
    scrollViewer1.UpdateLayout();
    scrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(200);
```